# How to detect hyperlinks inside a GridView cell and style them differently than other text?

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a GridView with two columns, *Date* and *Message*. Data bound to the GridView can contain one or more URLs in the *message* column, e.g.:

```
Date        Message
6/18/2014   "Site http://somesite was created."
6/18/2014   "There was a problem when trying to access https://www.google.com"
...
```

What I'm trying to do is to **style only the URLs in the *Message* column as hyperlinks**, i.e. apply hyperlink style to them, so that normal text will have different style/color than the hyperlinks. I don't really know how to approach this. Is there a better and less expensive solution than processing each cell manually as it is added?

GridView:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gridView1" runat="server" 
AutoGenerateColumns="false"
Width="100%"
CssClass="gridviewstlye"        
EnableModelValidation="True">
<AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="gridviewalter" />
<Columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Date" HeaderText="Date" />       
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Message" HeaderText="Message"/>
</Columns>
<HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" Font-Bold="True" Height="33px" />   
<RowStyle CssClass="gridrowstyle" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't have different styles for text if it's inside one element.

It will be very tedious on the other hand to process it from code behind.

You have to iterate the items of your gridview and find the row that contains http.

If it has http, you have to count the instance of the word http and create a loop.

Inside the loop you need to find the http and the space character next to it (to extract the URL). Save it to a variable and have something like

```
r.Cells(1).Text = r.Cells(1).Text.Replace(URLVariable, "<a href=" & _
URLVariable & ">" & URLVariable & "</a>"
```